# Can someone explain how the Bundle Identifier gets set in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm getting an error when I build my React Native project. The error says "Failed to chmod" and then lists a location and says "No such file or directory." My hunch is that this could be an error with my Bundle Identifier. I would like to verify that in Xcode, it matches with whatever React Native is generating for me.

Is this a right way of thinking? I'll accept an answer that just explains how it's set but I'm also trying to figure out this error so I can build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle identifier is set through the native builds. For instance, if you open your iOS project Xcode (it's stored under the ios folder in your react native project), select the project file in the file view, and then check out the General tab. You'll see the app name, versions, and the *bundle identifier*.

For Android, it's a little more complex. You can see the bundle ID in your app level `build.gradle` file, under android / defaultConfig / applicationId.

However, that bundle ID is also stored in a lot of places for Android. For example, it's also in your android manifest, and the actual project structure and class names are based off of it. So if your bundle ID is `com.company.project`, you'll have folders com/company/project where your android code is stored. You can also see it at the top of your `mainApplication` and `mainActivity` files.

It's pretty easy to change in Xcode (just modify that field you got to above), but Android requires a little more work, if that's what you're after.

Anyways, your main problem about chmod is related to permissions (chmod sets permissions of files). Can you post the exact error? I would suggest a fresh `npm install` or `yarn`, as it may be a missing package.